# Cassandra bulk insert operation, internally

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am looking for Cassandra/CQL's cousin of the common SQL idiom of `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...` and have been unable to find anything to do such an operation programmatically or in CQL. Is it just not supported?

My use case is to do a reasonably bulky copy from one table to another. I don't need any particular concurrent guarantees, but it's a lot of data so I'd like to avoid the additional network overhead of writing a client that retrieves data from one table, then issues batches of inserts into the other table. I understand that the changes will still need to be transported between nodes of the Cassandra cluster according to the replication set-up, but it seems reasonable for there to be an "internal" option to do a bulk operation from one table to another. Is there such a thing in CQL or elsewhere? I'm currently using Hector to talk to Cassandra.

Edit: it looks like `sstableloader` might be relevant, but is awfully low-level for something that I'd expect to be a fairly common use case. Taking just a subset of rows from one table to another also seems less than trivial in that framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, this is not supported natively.  (Another alternative would be a map/reduce job.)  Cassandra's API focuses on short requests for applications at scale, not batch or analytical queries.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. I assume that the lack of this is a design decision rather than an omission, then? Or do you think it's likely something like this will make it in eventually?