# Copying a value from table to another using cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a very huge table in cassandra that consists of (caseid ,timestamp, activity)as columns with caseid and timestamp being the primary key.The values of caseid are getting repeated and I want to extract the 1st value of activity corresponding to a caseid and put it to another table(named initialActivity) that consists of only activity. Can someone please help me as to how I can acheive this using a cql query.Thanks.

Comment: do you have any existing query for that ? have you tried yet anything?

Comment: @Rahul:Yes, intially I was trying to do things using a Java program, where I extracted all the caseids, and then for each caseid,I run the query select activity from table where caseid="111" limit 1; and collect it in a String object,and then INSERT INTO initialActivity(activity text) values (""); But now I  do not want to use JAVA and want to do only in cql. Thanks.

Comment: Please try the following query and let me know.
insert into initialActivity(activity) 
SELECT activity FROM preActivity where caseId = 111 LIMIT 1

Comment: You cannot do this via cql only, see this q/a: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633624/cassandra-bulk-insert-operation-internally

Comment: For batch requests like this you most likely want to use a batch analytics framework like Hadoop or Spark.

Answer (score -2):

Please try this

```
Insert into initialActivity() values 
(select activity from preActivity where caseId = 111 LIMIT 1 );
```

Only first rows with column `activity` with `caseId = 111` will get inserted into `initialActivity` table

Please refer this for more info
[CQL](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html)

Comment: I executed the query INSERT INTO initial(events) values (select substatus from cqldata where caseid='1-734922986' LIMIT 1)...but it shows me the error no viable alternative at input 'select'. I am not able to figure out what is wrong here or does cassandra support such queries?

Comment: please update the question with the query you are trying and the error you are facing.

Comment: This syntax is not supported in cassandra

Comment: @mikea: So, there is no way in cql that I  can get the 1st  value of an activity corresponding to a caseid. Can this only be done through some application(like Java application) as I was doing earlier.